# How to invoke an exported function from DLL written in C/C++ which return type is char* or string?

Tags: c++, dll, go

We designed C/C++ DLL just like this:

```
WIN32_DLL_EXPORT int FnRetInt(int i)
{
   ....
   return 32 ;
} 

WIN32_DLL_EXPORT char* FnRetString()
{
   return "THIS IS A TEST STRING" ;
}
```

when we invoke these two functions in `Go` by using syscall:

```
hd:=syscall.NewLazyDLL(dll_path)
proc:=hd.NewProc(dll_func_name)
ret:=proc.Call()
```

we found:

`FnRetInt` worked ok, but `FnRetString` didn't. `proc.Call` return type is `uintptr`, how can we change it to the type we wanted (for exsample: char* or string)?

Answer (score 2):

A `uintptr` is a Go type that represents a pointer. You can use the `unsafe` package and convert it to `unsafe.Pointer`, and then you can convert an `unsafe.Pointer` into any Go pointer type. So you could do something like

```
str := (*uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(ret))
```

to get a `*uint8` back.

Comment: for your codez: it got:
get result:  0x30f7c01c
how to get the value from this point?

Comment: @hsine: Yes, that's a pointer value. Presumably it points to a series of characters, with a NUL termination. Cgo provides a function `C.GoString()` which takes a `*C.char` and returns a `string`, but if you're not using Cgo then it's going to take more work to turn this into a usable `string`.

Comment: @hsine: What you can do is construct a `[]byte` slice and start copying bytes from your `*uint8` in until you hit NUL, and then you can convert that to a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at syscall.Getwd windows implementation http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/syscall/syscall_windows.go#323. It is different from your problem:

- it passes buffer to the dll, instead of receiving it from dll;
- the data is uint16s (Microsoft WCHARs), instead of uint8s;
- GetCurrentDirectory tells us how long resulting string is going to be, while your example, probably, expects you to search for 0 at the end;

But should give you enough clues.

Alex